# Left join issue using having clause with sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `products(id, name)` and `products_cost(id, sid, cost)`.

I'm trying to get a list of products whose total cost is less than 1000 including products that has no cost.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT a.name, SUM(b.cost) AS price
FROM products a
LEFT JOIN products_cost b
ON a.id = b.sid
GROUP BY a.name
HAVING SUM(b.cost)<1000;
```

The above SQL only gives the list of product name that includes cost and I want the output list to include product name that doesn't include cost as well.

Comment: Could you provide some samlpe data and expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to check for `null` values in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT p.name, SUM(pc.cost) AS price
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     products_cost pc
     ON p.id = b.sid
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING SUM(pc.cost) < 1000 OR SUM(pc.cost) IS NULL;
```

Note that I also fixed the logic (`salary` doesn't makes sense in the `SUM()`).  And I introduced *meaningful* table aliases -- abbreviations for the table names.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. And pardon for my broken logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add an `IFNULL` expression in your `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT a.name, SUM(b.cost) AS price
FROM products a
LEFT JOIN products_cost b
ON a.id = b.sid
GROUP BY a.name
HAVING SUM(IFNULL,b.cost,0)<1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

use subquery and join

```
   select p.*,a.s as cost from product p left join (
     select pid,sum(cost) as s
     from products_cost
    group by pid
    having s<1000 ) a on p.id=a.pid
```